# PHPMailer unable to require files

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer without Composer in a small containerized project.

I have followed the PHPMailer guide and setup my import as follows:

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

When I try to run this I get:

```php
Warning: require(PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/EmailerNotifier.php on line 4
```

As far as I can tell all the permissions and file owner are correct for the directories and files.

Other imports in my php container work fine. If I copy one of the files - say `Exception.php` up to the parent directory the import works, eg:

```php
require 'Exception.php'; //This works if file is moved to the same directory as the calling class
```

If I create my own sub-directory, ie: `test/src/test.php` then that file can be imported fine. It is just the PHPMailer sub-directory that is failing.

Is this a Docker issue? Is there some other permission I need in docker to use PHPMailer?

EDIT: Adding `__DIR__` to get the full path to the file eg: `require __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer...` does not fix the issue.

Comment: Your question misses the information of the absolute paths of those three files to require. All permissions apply.

Comment: If it says permission denied, it means you don't have permission. There isn't any ambiguity there.

Comment: All the files have the same permissions (Both the working ones and the failing ones). Whether I view them check them on the host machine or the docker-compose ls: 644. They are all owned by the same user. Unless docker is changing ownership on the container I am lost. Additionally. if the file had the wrong permission or owner why would it work when I move it two levels up?

Comment: diagnose it from the script's point of view - try pointing `is_readable()` at those source files from your script, or getting info about permissions and ownership with `stat()`

Comment: Ok, it turned out the script needed to be executable if located in the sub-directory but not when I pulled it up into the root directory. It only seemed to be an issue for the docker container not the parent system. Even though the owner had x permission in both cases I gues docker was using a different user inside the container?